# Filtering questions by OP's reputation

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation

Is it possible to filter questions so that we only see questions posted by people with more than $n$ reputation points? Perhaps better would be if we could only see questions posted in the last $d$ days by people with more than $n$ reputation points.

The motivation is that people with more reputation are more likely to post better questions.

Comment: See also: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/21498/see-questions-recently-posed-by-high-rep-users

Comment: meta.SE: [Can we filter questions by reputation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3987/can-we-filter-questions-by-reputation)

Answer (score 12):

I would not be happy with this, as it might seriously limit the attention given to questions posted by those users who could be highly competent posters of good questions, but would be "filtered out" from many users attention purely due to being relatively new to the site. When I first joined MSE, I would certainly not have felt encouraged by the idea that my questions could be invisible to those of the higher-reputation community who were using such a filter.

Comment: I appreciate your comment. From time to time I would prefer to avoid seeing (likely) homework questions that are not tagged as such.

Comment: I am sure that we would all like to see fewer homework questions which are not tagged as such, but I am not convinced that this suggestion is a good way to go about it.

Comment: @OldJohn: The decision to utilize such a feature seems best left to the individual. Of course, no one would compel you to use such a feature.

Answer (score 7):

There is no chance of SE implementing this: they want low-quality content seen and *dealt with* by the users, not hidden. But you can have such filtering for yourself, with a little effort. I describe two methods.

**Method 1**: use the Data Explorer. The query [recent questions from reputable users](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathematics/query/153587/recent-questions-from-reputable-users) gives the list of 500 most recent questions by users with a given amount of reputation (or more). The question titles are links to actual questions. Tags and number of answers are also listed, to help you decide which questions to pursue. Negatively scored questions and closed questions are excluded.

*Disadvantages*: (1) The data is not current. Data Explorer operates with a data dump that is created weekly (on a weekend). (2) The question list is not as easy to read as on the website.

**Method 2**: use a client-side script. I made a [Chrome extension](http://dropproxy.com/f/55F) that hides all questions from users with $<100$ reputation. ([Installation instructions](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted.html#unpacked)). Having installed the extension, you can browse MSE normally, without seeing any questions from low-rep users*.

The script uses jQuery and is very simple:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.question-summary').each(function() {
    var question = $(this);
    question.find('.reputation-score').each(function() {
      var score = $(this).html();  
      if (score.length<3) { question.css('display', 'none'); }
      }); 
   }); 
});
```

Option: change `(score.length<3)` to `(score.length<2)` to filter out only the users with single-digit reputation.

(*) Correction: this does not quite work as originally advertised. If the question was edited or answered by another user, that user's reputation will be placed where the question owner's reputation was originally. The filter works well for newly posted question, though.

Looking up the reputation of question owner for edited/answered questions  requires a call to StackExchange API; it is not present in the HTML markup of the question list.

Comment: Your methods are useful, but please remove your post. (Why? See OldJohn's answer)